# How do I create multiple axis labels in R?

Tags: r

This is my code:

```
ggplot(q19.long,aes(x=species,score,fill=species))
+geom_boxplot(alpha=0.5)
+labs(y= "Score", x = "",title=questiontitle)
+theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),legend.title=element_blank())
+scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("Rat","Vampire fly","Blackberry","Smooth-billed ani","Goat","Frog","Cat","Guava","Dog","Elephant grass"))
```

This is the Plot I get[image: What I produced]

On my Y axis I have the label "Score". But I want TWO labels. One right next to the number 5 saying "Strongly Agree", the other one right next to the number 1, saying "Strongly Disagree". Just like in the picture below:
[image: What I want to achieve]

I've been trying different things for hours but all I can do is add second axis but no second labels. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" solution I came up with is just changing the ylab from "score" to "stongly agree               strongly disagree". I just put in a lot of space bars. Not very elegant but it works.

Comment: Please provide an example!